# Python in ArcGIS. Need get access to elements of strings

Tags: python, cursor, arcgis, arcpy

ArcGIS 10.0

I used arcpy.UpdateCursor for access to my field:

```
import arcpy
import sys

layer = sys.argv[1]#my table
field = sys.argv[2]#target field in table

cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(layer)

for row in cursor:
    attrString = row.getValue("field")
    subString = attrString[3]
    row.setValue(field,subString)
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

My problem is that I want to access the element of string, which has variable "row", but is it not support indexes and not iterable.
Can you please recommend other methods ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "access the element of string"? Are you trying to get data by row from a different field?

Comment: I mean if I want access to index of "row" variable, row[1], I have error - "Row' object does not support indexing"

Comment: So you want to know which row you're in? Or you want to know the value of another field (e.g. `1`) and if it's equal to `"E"` then update `field`?

Comment: I right understand that "row" it's strings of "field" ?

Comment: No; the `row` represents an individual feature out of the feature class (or layer) that the `cursor` is iterating through. Various "fields" are the index  to access attributes of that feature (e.g. `row.getValue("Count")` may equal `5`); the value might be a string or integer or float, depending on the source data. You can't access it by index (in ArcGIS 10.0 at least), it has to be by field name.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer. Can you please recommend other methods ? I want get access to element of string, for example: i have layer.shp, layer.shp has attributive table, attributive table has field - "Streets", so I want get access to elements of each string field "Streets".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The ArcGIS help pages about [UpdateCursors](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//000v0000003m000000) and [Accessing data using cursors](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001q000000) are useful background information.*

The `UpdateCursor` function creates a "cursor" object, which is made up of "row" objects. Each of these rows represents an individual feature of the feature class or layer.

To access data (whether reading or updating) from a `row` object, you need to specify the *field name* instead of a numerical index. So, if you're checking whether attribute `letter` is equal to `E`:

```
if row.getValue("letter") == "E":
    # do stuff
```

Once you have gotten that attribute value stored in another variable, you can access elements of the resulting string and do any Python string manipulation you want:

```
attrString = row.getValue("street")
subString = attrString[11]
newString = attrString.replace("B", "t")
attrString[11] = "t"
```

Comment: I don't understand what is "letter".   i have layer.shp, layer.shp has attributive table, attributive table has field - "Streets", so I want get access to elements of each string field "Streets". First string of field "Streets" contains "1-st Main sBreet" (for example), and i want get access to [11] element of this string, and replace it to "t", that i get "1-st Main street"

Comment: It's just an example attribute name.

Comment: ok :) How i understand in my case attribute name it's "field" ?

Comment: You can do something like `arcpy.ListFields(layer)` to get all the field names, but usually I find it's easier to just look at the table and decide what attributes I'm going to work with.

Comment: I update script above, can you please look it ? I want give each string of field "field" value with [3] index. But i get <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.

Comment: Error 999999 is the least informative error there is. Which line is it failing on?

Comment: Running script translit...
<type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (translit).
Failed at Wed Mar 23 16:26:29 2016 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)

Comment: I think you're going to need to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that, I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot for your help, and have nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolve. I replace "field" to field and now works fine.

```
import arcpy
import sys

layer = sys.argv[1]#my table
field = sys.argv[2]#target field in table

cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(layer)

for row in cursor:
    attrString = row.getValue(field)
    subString = attrString[3]
    row.setValue(field,subString)
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Work with the newer version of cursors:
arcpy.da.UpdateCursor and you will have the row[field] indexing for which I believe you were originally looking.

You have to be using ArcGIS >= 10.1 for access to da. cursors.
[ArcGIS 10.3 Help for arcpy.da](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm)